# jQuery syntax error with unexpected token

Tags: jquery, syntax

Sorry for basic... I expect some pro's will mark me down - again, however I have been struggling to see the error of my ways:

Unexpected token { is my error, and the code is:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function {
  $('people.img').click(function() {
    $('.peopleSummary').addClass('hello');
  })
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {//<-- missig () after function
    $('people.img').click(function () {
        $('.peopleSummary').addClass('hello');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no html element called `people`, this is a incorrect selector

```
 $('people.img')
```

Also to define a function you need `()`, otherwise you get also a syntax error

```
$(document).ready(function {
```

---

So try this, assuming your `people` is a `class` (otherwise use `#` for a ID):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.people.img').click(function() {
    $('.peopleSummary').addClass('hello');
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If people is a `class` then try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.people.img').click(function() {
    $('.peopleSummary').addClass('hello');
  })
});
```

If it is an `id` try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#people.img').click(function() {
    $('.peopleSummary').addClass('hello');
  })
});
```